# Latest update of Oberdiek package: \declaretheoremstyle not working anymore

Tags: errors, thmtools, oberdiek

Just updated to the 20 December build of the Oberdiek package, on my TeXLive installation. Files that compiled without problems are now throwing the following error:

> ```
> ./Preamble.tex:78: Undefined control sequence.
> \kv@processor@default ...lt {#1}{\etex@unexpanded 
>                                                   {#2}}}\KVS@temp
> ```

which appears when I use `\declaretheoremstyle` of the `thmtools` package.
The packages `kvdefinekeys` and `kvsetkeys` are installed and working well.

Does anybody know an explanation and a workaround?

Here is a compilable example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle{mythmstyle}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show a compilable example?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Done.

Comment: As a workaround, you can load `\usepackage{etexcmds}`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik well, it does work know. Thank you very much for your perfect reactivity & suggestion. Can you please post your comment as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik and if you have one minute, can you also explain to me a bit what happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As part of The Big Oberdiek Split™, the `kvsetkeys` package (loaded by `thmtools`) was removed from the Oberdiek bundle, and the `etexcmds` package was removed from `kvsetkeys` (probably because its usefulness is debatable) in [this commit](https://github.com/ho-tex/kvsetkeys/commit/1753342915728a0d08675b48bbad309faeff4718), so `thmtools`, which relied on `kvsetkeys` loading `etextools` now breaks. That is one of the reasons why relying on a package loading another package is a bad idea: if you need the package, *load it*.

That said, as a workaround until `thmtools` is fixed, you can load `etexcmds` manually.

Answer (score 6):

I uploaded a fixed version to CTAN that takes the dependency out, but it will take a couple of days to arrive.

**I don't consider myself the maintainer of the package though ... so anyone really interested in this package please consider taking on the maintenance.  I'm already doing support for too many packages that aren't mine.**

Comment: Thanks for fixing :-)

Comment: Xmas present :-) ... well asuming I made no mistake

Comment: @FrankMittelbach thanks for your present! everything works fine again for me as before, without using the etxcmds package

Comment: @brunoh welcome --- appreciation and sponsoring of LaTeX development and maintenance is possible :-)

Comment: Using TL utility I wasn't able to get the (strongly) needed files up to know.  At which repository are they available?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools  but it should be available through std TL update mechanisms for a number of days now.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thanks a lot, but in my case ltxcmds.sty is missing ...  I've tried several depositories for upgrading but is all ends up with that missing package ...  Using TL Utility under latest MacOs, in case that matters.

Comment: FWIW ... Using the Oberdiek-stuff (due to PSTricks) I had to install ltxcmds as well as etexcmds manually.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe quite possible but that isa totally different issue. I haven't undone the split of the Overdiek stuff, so if you have other packages that rely on the full bundle then you now need to load more of the individual packages from the bundle because they aren't all  loaded in one go. What I did was to remove the dependency on etexcmds for thmtools because it was unnecessary and the package was broken even if etexcmds was available on your machine. Why you seem to have to install any of the packages "manually" I have no clue. On my Mac it installed automatically if update was triggered.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thanks a lot; I don't have a clue either why the packages didn't show up in TeXLive Utility on my latest updates.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe my experience is that sometimes you have to change your mirror because the one used is lagging behind for whatever reason but this may not be your problem if other updates show up.