# MikTeX 2.9.7300 problem pmboxdraw.sty & kvdefinekeys.sty missing from oberdiek

Tags: miktex, oberdiek

Is there a problem with MikTeX or the oberdiek package?

I'm running pdflatex, which never finishes, and this is the end of the miktex-pdftex.log:

```
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository: http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: visiting repository http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2020-02-11 18:46:15,318-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2020-02-11 18:46:15,576-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: 0.20 MB, 6.55 Mbit/s
2020-02-11 18:46:15,717-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository digest: 213074cb995a6349e3caaa57c829aaf2
2020-02-11 18:46:16,546-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to download 9404699 bytes
2020-02-11 18:46:16,546-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to install 109 file(s) (1 package(s))
2020-02-11 18:46:17,135-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/oberdiek.tar.lzma...
2020-02-11 18:46:18,019-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: 9.40 MB, 85.79 Mbit/s
2020-02-11 18:46:18,116-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
2020-02-11 18:46:23,118-0500 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The installed file does not exist.
2020-02-11 18:46:23,118-0500 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
2020-02-11 18:46:23,118-0500 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2020-02-11 18:46:23,118-0500 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 59
2020-02-11 18:46:23,118-0500 INFO  miktex-pdftex - finishing with exit code 1
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521303/134574. `kvdefinekeys` and a bunch other packages were removed from `oberdiek` (for maintainability). If you update your packages (in both admin and user mode), then MiKTeX should sort everything out

Comment: You should update package database from MoKTeX console and ask to install missing packages on the fly.

Comment: As always with MikTeX issues: Update your system in Admin and User mode. Then go to the Console and select "Tasks > Update package database" again in Admin and User mode. Then try to recompile your document. Ideally the on-the-fly package install window pops up and will ask your permission to install the stand-alone packages (which were split from Oberdiek as explained above)

Comment: This is a known MiKTeX limitation documented here: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/436